# qmllive plugin cannot be loaded for module

Tags: qt, qml

Trying to integrate [qmllive](https://doc.qt.io/QtQmlLive/index.html) with my project. Qmllive live bench have problems with finding qml QtQuick.Controls module. Live bench error log:

```
plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Controls": Cannot load library G:\tools\Qt\5.11.1\mingw53_32\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

etc. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

For future generations.

Log is misleading. The real cause of error, is lacking of several .dll files in qmllive exe directory, omitted by windeployqt.